# WMI query for getting performance of a running server

Tags: wmi, wmi-query

Which WMI query can I use to get the performance information of a running httpd service?

```
hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
        bstr_t("WQL"), 
        bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process Where Name='httpd'"),
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
        NULL,
        &pEnumerator);


    IWbemClassObject *pclsObj;  
    ULONG uReturn = 0;

    while (pEnumerator)
    {
        HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, 
            &pclsObj, &uReturn);


        if(0 == uReturn)
        {
            break;
        }

        VARIANT vtProp;

        // Get the value of the Name property
        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"Name", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);

        wcout << " test : " << vtProp.bstrVal << endl;

        VariantClear(&vtProp);

        pclsObj->Release();     
    }
```

Comment: which property should I use in order to know the performance of my service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add filter for Process Name in this code:

```
strComputer ="."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process",,48)

        wscript.echo "Computer Name" & "," & "Process Name" & ","& "CPU Usage"
For Each objItem in colProcesses
if objItem.Name <> "Idle"  and objItem.Name <> "_Total" then 
        wscript.echo strcomputer & "," & objItem.Name & ","& objItem.PercentProcessorTime
end if
Next
```

Comment: updated my question. my current code only display the name of the service :(